# How to translate "open source" and "free software" and keep the distinction?

Tags: modismos, traducción

In English, when describing software you say "[open source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source)" to refer to software that's source code has been made available under a license.

"[Free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)" refers to 'truly free' software that can be used and modified freely.

Normally, I would say "software libre", but that doesn't really seem to capture the full concept. How would a native speaker translate each of these terms while preserving the distinction?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

> Open Source: "Código abierto"
>
> Free Software: "Software libre/gratis"

There's no way to get confused.

Comment: fuente abierta as an (bad/good?) alternative to código abierto.

Comment: @snoram "Fuente abierta" doesn't work because "fuente" by it self is never used when speaking about source code. You'd say "código fuente" if you want to be clear about it, "código abierto" works because "abierto" (literally opened) implies accessibility.

Comment: Estoy en desacuerdo: _Free software_ se traduce como **Software libre**, nunca como _Software gratis_. Nota que _free_ tiene dos acepciones: "libre" y "gratis" siendo la primera la acepción correcta.

Answer (score 10):

According to [Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_abierto) it looks like the (or at least a) proper translation of *open source* is *código abierto*. I'm pretty sure I've also seen just the phrase *open source* used, without translation.  Likewise, I've seen *free software* used without translation (in fact the Wikipedia page linked even does that).

At least in Spanish the distinction between free (gratis) software and free (libre) software isn't as confusing as in English!

Comment: +1 for that bit about gratis vs. libre.

Answer (score 3):

It is known as (or translated as)

> Software Libre

or

> Software de código libre

Answer (score 2):

The great rms (Richard Stallman) uses "el software libre" in his Spanish talks, though I can't remember how he references merely "open source". I suppose like many terms it should be OK to just say "open source". At least there's a difference between "software gratis" and "software libre" :)